# TFS 2010 Build - unit test dependencies missing

Tags: automated-tests, tfsbuild

I have created a new build definition for TFS 2010. After building my C# solution I would like it to execute a couple of unit tests. These unit tests require an XML input file, so I have a [DeploymentItem] attribute to the test methods which provides the relative path the XML files. If I run the unit tests from within Visual Studio they pass ok.

When the unit tests get run following a build (via my build definition), they fail with: "Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.BizTalkTestAssertFailException: Input file  does not exist..."

It would be great if I could get to a trace of what the build agent was trying to do, to help with troubleshooting.

Does anyone know how to get such a trace output? I guess I could increase the verbosity of the trace output from the main solution under test but I don't think that would give me any indication of where the build agent was looking for the test input XML or why?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Needed to click the "View Log" link from the screen that's displayed following the build. I had been looking at the default view of "View Summary"